# Why jsp cannot reach its css file in SpringMVC?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a SpringMVC project. Upon running the project in tomcat7 I get the following message:

`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myproject/resources/css/welcome.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'`

CSS does not get applied:

[image]

I've tried available solutions but none of them worked and none of them actually explained what was going on.

I have a simple `welcome.jsp` in `/WEB-INF/jsp`. Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/welcome.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="font-HarabaraHand">
        <p class="centrify">Poem Collection</p>
    </div>
    <div id="font-Goodfoot">
        <p class="centrify2">What would you like to do?</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My `welcome.css` file lies in `src/main/webapp/resources/css/`.
My Spring configuration is java based, **DispatcherServlet** class is in `AppInit.java file`:

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    // this method is automatically invoked on application startup
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext webcntx = getWebCntx();

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(webcntx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
                "DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(webcntx));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getWebCntx() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebAppConfiguration.class);
        return context;
    }
}
```

And finally in `WebAppConfig.java` file:

```
@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/resources/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/").setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD);;

    }
}
```

My welcome page controller:

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }
}
```

Here is my project structure:

[image: upper part]
[image: welcome.jsp file]

**1. Why my `welcome.css` file cannot be reached?**

**2. How I can correct my mappings configuration?**

I would really appreciate an explanation or a link about Spring url mappings config.

Comment: Try `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/welcome.css"` and let know

Comment: Sorry, your variant does not work. My folder structure is `src/main/webapp/resources/css/welcome.css`

Comment: then just try to check that weather you giving path is indicating that file of not try (f.exits) if that is true then file is getting path

Comment: Do not put your jsp files into WEB-INF! They should be in the `src/main/webapp` folder.

Comment: @kromit why? I read exactly the opposite. In WEB-INF folder .jsp files are not accessible from the client side, while in other folders they are. My project structure is ok, there are plenty tutorials with the same setup, I thought that maybe my mappings are wrong.

Comment: jsp files do not need to be "protected" since they will be processed by the jsp servlet, which renders them to HTML. The content of a jsp file can not be downloaded anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using Java Config:

1. Create the following subdirectory structure: `src/main/webapp/public/css`
2. Put your css files in `src/main/webapp/public/css` (e.g. `src/main/webapp/public/css/welcome.css`)
3. Define an handler for public resources:

   ```
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
       if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/public/**")) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**")
                   .addResourceLocations("/public/")
                   .setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD); // You have to define a cache period.
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add a security exception:

   ```
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/**");
   }
   ```
5. Link you css files (by defining a relative path):

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
   ...
   <head>
       <c:set var="url">${pageContext.request.requestURL}</c:set>
       <base href="${fn:substring(url, 0, fn:length(url) - fn:length(pageContext.request.requestURI))}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/welcome.css" />
   </head>
   ```

Comment: this looks a way more complicated than I thought it would be, why? Just take a look http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: If you are using Spring with Java Config, it represents a reliable way to set up your application.

Comment: tried it, didn't help. `welcome.css` file does not get applied.

Comment: You did something wrong. The solution above results well-tested on an enterprise project (just as is).

Answer (score 0):

**@vdenotaris** answer is correct

My configuration didn't work because of my `pom.xml` file setup.
maven-war-plugin had `<warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>` and my `/src/main/webapp/resources/css` has never been detected by maven. Once I moved my jsp files to `/src/main/webapp/` all was ok.

So, either you leave everything (css resources and other stuff) in `WebContent\WEB-INF\` folder or move everything to `/src/main/webapp`